# RemoteException wrapping UiPath.Core.ElementOperationException

Tags: python, xaml, web-scraping, automation, uipath

I am working on automating the desktop using UIPath.
Inside Citrix machine. and I created a Fast API to trigger the robot processor.
It working perfectly when the Citrix machine connected. but when the Citrix machine disconnect it through the above error
I tried to use ” Element Exists ” and increase “Timeout” time it doesn’t help

The error “Timeout reached” occurs when the robot is waiting for some elements to appear on the screen and the element is not available on the screen even after the 30sec(default).

Comment: are you using attended or unattended bot. When machines are disconnected you will require unattended bot (for your specific task.). Try to use Simulate property for Clicks and Type Into activities (these might help you)